# how to mock servlet context in mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I am writing test cases for servlets. In tests i am not able to pass servlet context variable to servlet using mockito. I tried but in servlet it is giving null pointer exception. below i am providing code and test code :

code is :

```
public class httpt_vb_getTableNames extends HttpServlet implements SingleThreadModel {

    int userId;
    String userName;
    String userPassword;

    public void service (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println( "came to httpt_vb_getTableNames servlet");
        response.setContentType( "text/plain");
        ServletContext sc = getServletContext();
        ServletOutputStream servletOut = response.getOutputStream ();
}
```

test code is :

```
public class http_vb_getTableNamesServletTest {
@Mock
HttpServletRequest request;
@Mock
HttpServletResponse response;
@Mock
HttpSession session;
@Mock
RequestDispatcher rd;
@Mock
ServletOutputStream  servletOut;
@Mock
ServletContext sc;
@Mock
FilterConfig filterConfig;
public final static String Seperator = new Character((char)1).toString();
public final static String ContentDelimeter = new Character((char)2).toString();

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws Exception 
{
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    sc=mock(ServletContext.class);
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    DataSet ds=new DataSet();

    String buffer=ds.getUserId()+Seperator+ds.getUsername();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(bos);
    out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("request.txt"));
    out.write(buffer.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    out.closeEntry();
    out.close();
    bos.close();

    String b64String = Base64.encodeBase64String(bos.toByteArray());
    Reader inputString = new StringReader(b64String);
    BufferedReader reqbuffer = new BufferedReader(inputString);
    httpt_vb_getTableNames servlet=new httpt_vb_getTableNames();

    when(request.getReader()).thenReturn(reqbuffer);
    when(request.getServletContext()).thenReturn(sc);
    when(response.getOutputStream()).thenReturn(servletOut);
    when(sc.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/admin/chooseNeighborhood.jsp")).thenReturn(rd);
    when(sc.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/admin/joinNeighborhood.jsp")).thenReturn(rd);
    servlet.service(request, response);

    ArgumentCaptor<String> bufferCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
    verify(servletOut).print(bufferCaptor.capture());
    String responseBody = bufferCaptor.getValue();       

    ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decodeBase64(responseBody.toString().getBytes())));
    zipIn.getNextEntry();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    IOUtils.copy(zipIn, out1);
    sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(out1.toString("UTF-8"));

    String[] res=sb.toString().split(Seperator);        
    AssertJUnit.assertEquals("Success",res[0]);
}
```

}

can anyone suggest me how to mock servlet context in mocktio ?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to Initialize Servlet Config through mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50350992/how-to-initialize-servlet-config-through-mockito)

Comment: Where exactly do you get the NullPointerException?

Comment: in code for mentioned line 
ServletContext sc = getServletContext();

Comment: @Oleg Skylar i tried that answer for servlet context it is not working

Comment: Have you tried calling `servlet.init(sc)` ?

Comment: yes i tried init method.

Comment: for servlet.init(......) for this method we are passing servlet config

Comment: Yes, but the ServletConfig contains the ServletContext. If you make `getServletContext` return your mock instance, it should be picked up.

Comment: yes it passed using servlet.init(config).
in the servlet i am redirecting to jsp page using response.sendRedirect(url). how can i get that url in mockito

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171195/discussion-between-jaydeep-bobade-and-thilo).